# MySQL phpmyadmin procedure selecting free seats next to each other in cinema reservation system

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im making a cinema reservation system in PHP and MySQL, the problem is that i need to make procedure with two arguments - number of seats wanted and showing id. It is expected to return free seats next to each other. The project of tables is in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkFM2.jpg . I've already made a procedure that return count of free seats for some showing, but have no idea how to make it returning free seats next to each other (maybe possibly in the middle of cinema hall) depending on argument "l_m". I  assume the hall always has 100 seats, and each row is numbered from 1 to 10. Any help?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `reservations`(IN `id_s` INT(5), IN `l_m` INT(5))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
SELECT l.num_of_seats-COUNT(r.id_reservations) AS free FROM reservations r
JOIN showings s ON s.id_showing = r.id_showing
JOIN halls l ON l.id_hall = s.id_hall
WHERE s.id_showing = id_s;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `I assume the hall always has 100 seats, and each row is numbered from 1 to 10` This seems like a considerable assumption.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1v5eO This is how our cinema look like